# Load more button should disappear

Tags: jquery

I am using some code to show content with load more button. Every thing is working fine. But only one thing that is causing problem is Load more button is still showing when all the content is loading. My query is the load more button should disappear when all the contents have been loaded.

html code for load more button:

```
<div id="loadMore"  class="g-btn type_primary size_big ldm" style="cursor:pointer;  display:none; width: 307px; margin: auto; font-size: 26px;  padding: 10px 0px; ">Load more Content</div>
```

Jquery code for load more:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=10;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+10 <= size_li) ? x+10 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });

    if($('#myList li').length > 10) {
  //  $('#loadMore').show();
  $("#loadMore").css({"display":"block",

    });

}

    else {
   // $('#loadMore').hide();
   $("#loadMore").css({"display":"none",

    });
}
});
```

Comment: fiddle would be more helpful

Comment: please provide solution as per this fiddle query http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/     more is also still showing when all the ten item have been loaded. I want load more should disappear when all the content is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have syntax error in  `$("#loadMore").css({"display":"none",});`. Remove `,` after `none`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x = 10;
    $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x = (x + 10 <= size_li) ? x + 10 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt(' + x + ')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x = (x - 5 < 0) ? 3 : x - 5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt(' + x + ')').hide();
    });

    if ($('#myList li').length > 10) {
        //  $('#loadMore').show();
        $("#loadMore").css("display", "block");

    } else {
        // $('#loadMore').hide();
        $("#loadMore").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Or Simply use

`$("#loadMore").hide()` and `$("#loadMore").show()`

**Edit**

To get the number of displayed `li` use `:visible` selector

```
$('#myList li:visible').length
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/297/)

**Edit as per the requirement**

```
var count = 5;
$('#myList li:lt(' + count + ')').show();
$('#showLess').hide();
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    $('#showLess').show();
    count = $('#myList li:visible').length;
    $('#myList li:lt(' + (count + 5) + ')').show();
    if (count + 5 >= $('#myList li').length) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
$('#showLess').click(function () {
    $('#loadMore').show();
    count = $('#myList li:visible').length;
    $('#myList li:gt(' + (count - 5) + ')').hide();
    if ((count - 5) <= 5) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

[**Latest Fiddle Without hardcoding the length**](http://jsfiddle.net/nFd7C/317/)

Comment: I think {$('#myList li').length} is counting the total item not the how many item have been shown, Is there any way to count how many items have been shown then applying condition on it. may be!

Comment: Sir, load more is disappeared after first 10 items.. what about rest items

Comment: No... there are 25 items in the list and load more is disappeared only after showing 10 item . this is not the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56747/discussion-between-user3777827-and-anoop-joshi).

Comment: one more problem ! what if there are only 3 items means less then 5. Load more button is still showing when there is nothing to show. Not resolved yet , In your latest fiddle.

Comment: I have asked my question, which is not resolved yet, that's why I am asking for right answer so that the reader of this answer will get the right solution, not the half resolved answer.

Comment: will you please give me the right answer in jsfiddle! please!

Comment: @user3777827 create a fiddle which replicate your problem .I'll help to solve it

Comment: One more question, what if there are 2 items ! Ha Ha Ha Ha...just kidding...though I was not expecting your answer after the last comment about professionalism. But you are really a humble person. thanks again.