# Need to change "Load More" button name & function to "Show Less" after loading all contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

The script is working fine!  But **i need to change the button name and function from "Load more" to "Show Less" after loading all contents.**

*A stackoverflow answer is here:* [Load more button should disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566989/load-more-button-should-disappear)
*But no fade animation in this answer*.

Used code: https://codepen.io/vishnuprasad/pen/oBzqpd

```
$(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Try to look here : https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA

Answer (score 0):

Write Load More in label tag with id.

```
<label id="lblLoad">Load More</label>
```

add in your function

```
$('#lblLoad').html("Show Less");
```

change your id with

```
$("#loadMore").attr("id", "loadLess");
```

now write  a new function for click on id #load less .

Here is [Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZgeQO/). i triggered a alert here but you can do whatever you wanna do. Hope it helps.

Comment: could you write with fiddle?